# I have a issue in hibernate namedquery

Tags: hibernate, named-query

I'm using annotation for named query in hibernate.I have two classes a POJO class and a main class.The POJO class is as follows

```
@NamedQuery(
    name="findEmployeeName",
    query="select * from employee " 
)


@Entity
@Table(name="employee")
public class Employeenam {
    public String tostring(){return id+" " +name+ " " +salary+ " " +job;}

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id")
    int id;

    @Column(name="name")
    String name;

    @Column(name="salary")
    int salary;

    @Column(name="job")
    String job;

    public int setempId(){
        return id;
    }

    public void getempId(int Id){
        this.id=Id;
    }

    public String setempName(){
        return name;
    }

    public void getempName(String Name){
        this.name=Name;
    }

    public int getempSalary(){
        return salary;
    }

    public void setempSalary(int Salary){
        this.salary=Salary;
    }

    public String setempJob(){
        return job;
    }

    public void getempJob(String Job){
        this.job=Job;
    }
}

and the main class as follows

    public class FetchData{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Configuration configuration=new Configuration();
        configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        SessionFactory sfactory=configuration.buildSessionFactory();
        Session session=sfactory.openSession();
        Query query=session.getNamedQuery("findEmployeeName");
        query.setString("name", "dfdsf");
        query.setInteger("id", 34);
        query.setInteger("salary", 3543);
        query.setString("job", "dfgere");       
        session.close();
    }
    }
```

when i try to run this iam getting the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: 
Errors in named queries: findEmployeeName
```

can anyone tell me where i am going wrong?? I'm kind of new to hibernate..so please forgive me for any obvious errors....

Comment: Errors in named queries,so show us your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With HQL, you should reference entities instead of tables. So, it should be `Employeenam` instead of `employee`. If you're setting parameters to the query, you should also be using them in the query, making reference to the property names, according to the getters/setters (for instance, `empSalary`).

Try to write your query like this:

```
from Employeenam 
where empname = :name 
    and empid = :id 
    and empsalary = :salary 
    and empjob = :empjob
```

Also, you might consider changing your property names to match the getters/setters. If the property is called `id`, the corresponding getter/setter should be `getId()`/`setId(id)`.

Answer (score 1):

You are wrong in your named query try below

```
@NamedQueries({

    @NamedQuery(name="findEmployee",query="from Employeenam e" )
})
```

instead of

```
@NamedQuery(name="findEmployeeName",query="select * from employee " )
```

and inside your **FetchData.java** below one

```
    Configuration configuration=new Configuration();
    configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
    SessionFactory sfactory=configuration.buildSessionFactory();
    Session session=sfactory.openSession();
    Query query=session.getNamedQuery("findEmployee");

   // here you will get the list of employees
    List<employee> empList = query.list();

    session.close();
```

**Updated**:

If you need parametrized named query then try this

```
 @NamedQueries({

        @NamedQuery(name="findEmployeeByName",query="from Employeenam e where e.name =:name" )
    })
```

inside main method  replace Query line to this way

```
Query query=session.getNamedQuery("findEmployeeByName");

query.setString(¨name¨,¨subodh¨);    

       // here you will get the list of employees
        List<employee> empList = query.list();

        session.close();
```